# Create an application that restarts itself after n-seconds once

Tags: code-golf

In your favorite programming language, create an application that restarts itself once, after n seconds.

You need to find a way to restart after exiting the program. EG: run cmd to do it for you. Make sure it waits an amount of seconds specified by the user before restarting

For clarification: You can run a second program, or compile one at runtime to do the work for you.

Also, make sure the program works every time you execute it, not only once.

Example of algorithm:

```
If hasntrestartedalready
    read i
    exit
    wait(i)
    restart
end if
```

Least amount of bytes wins.

Comment: 1. What does "*Use any external programs/libraries that don't come with your OS*" mean in the context of OSes other than Windows and MacOS? I don't think even CPM distros were consistent in their accompanying utils. 2. What does"*invisible*" mean?

Comment: 1. Don't download binaries on runtime and use them to do the work for you, and don't have anything predownloaded to do the work for you. You can use any programming language, but you can't do eg
DownloadFile("http://bar.com/foo.exe") and then run it.
2. Invisible = no gui/window/form showing.

Comment: Why are you restricting the allowed algorithm?

Comment: I'm not restricting it. I'm trying to give an example of how I did it.

Comment: “The algorithm of your program should be:” If I'm correctly understandingthe meaning of “should” you are forbidding to use an other algorithm

Comment: Fair enough. Edited.

Comment: You are still restricting the algorithm, I will make an edit (You can still rollback it)

Comment: Could you clarify (by editing the question) whether it's OK for the program to replace itself via an exec (i.e. an atomic run-a-program-and-exit command)? Or does there have to be some time during which the program is not running at all in between the program exiting and starting. Additionally, is it legal to run a second program in the background, exit, and have the second program run you? Or must the restart not even be a child of the original execution?

Comment: Edited the post a bit for clarification.

For your first question, yes you can do that, but make sure the program works with every execution. So it won't stop working after I execute it once

For your second question, yes. You can use a second program as a helper for restarting.

Answer (score 3):

## Batch, <s>34</s> 28 bytes

```
timeout/t %1
if %1 neq [] %0
```

Input time in seconds as the first argument. If no argument is present, as well as after restarting, it spews out error messages (follow both commands with `2>NUL` to get rid of them). The new instance opens in the same window (OP said it's allowed).

Comment: Wait, if `%1` isn't `1`, then why is passing it to your script again going to work? Isn't it just infinite recursion based off of `%1`? Example: `script 482` will never *not* call `%0 %1`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be something like `if %1 neq 0 wait %1 %0 0`?

Comment: Wouldn't you do `if %1 neq 1 %0 1`?

Comment: @Timtech That's what I proposed, but the current answer nor your proposal wait for `%1` seconds, as required.

Comment: @SeeOneRhino Looks like this question was edited after being posted...

Comment: @Timtech I fixed the script! Probably. (a percent sign was where it shouldn't be) Also added timeout.

Comment: You probably can get away without the `/nobreak` and you don't need the space before `/t` (but you do need the space after).

Comment: Does this program actually restart itself after exiting? Or is it just exec-ing itself (i.e. replacing its running image with itself)? It's unclear to me whether the latter counts.

Comment: @ais523 I'm not sure how a script can do stuff after exiting, so it runs a new instance after the timeout and exits right after that.

Comment: @Neil I'll consider that, thanks!

Comment: @Sobsz: in my answer, I used the operating system's task scheduler to handle the restart. (I think figuring out a way to do that is the hardest part of the challenge.)

Comment: @Sobsz Yes that does count. As long as the arguments are passed, the program is restarted successfully after the seconds specified.

Comment: @P. Ktinos Yay!

Answer (score 2):

## bash + at, 29 bytes

```bash
at now+$[$1/60]min<<<bash\ $0
```

## zsh + at, 28 bytes

```bash
at now+$[$1/60]min<<<zsh\ $0
```

## bash + at or zsh + at, 23 bytes, arguably cheating

```bash
at now+$[$1/60]min<<<$0
```

The first version re-executes the program after the number of seconds given as a command-line argument (which must be a multiple of 60 because `at` has only minute granularity). `at` is a standard POSIX program for scheduling programs to be run in the future. The 29-byte and 28-byte programs each rerun the program with the shell it's designed for. The 23-byte program doesn't specify a shell, and thus may well accidentally rerun it with `sh`, which is likely to be unable to parse it; it's up to you whether you consider it reasonable for the restart to happen in the wrong language or not, so I presented both versions.

The time to wait is taken as a command-line argument. This means that the argument won't be present in the rerun, and thus the rerun will exit (with an error message due to the malformed expression, but which will be hidden by `at`; on some systems, it might be sent to you by email, but mine doesn't have that set up) rather than keep rerunning indefinitely.

`bash` considers the `$[]` syntax for arithmetic obsolete, but it still works and is shorter than the "official" syntax. `zsh` is fine with it, as far as I could tell from the documentation.

Comment: With your use of terms such as _likely_ and _acciddentally_ I will assume the program might not function correctly (restart after n-seconds) based on chance? If that's the case, that is not allowed, as the program must work each time it is executed. You can keep the other two however.

Comment: It's not based on chance, it's based on the configuration of the operating system it's run under. Additionally, the program *will* restart; it's just that it might restart under the wrong interpreter. (It's analogous to a Python program that restarts after *n* seconds, but ends up running under Ruby rather than Python; the restart itself functions, but you can't say much about the functioning of the program after the restart.)